# Can I get an overview of storage usage for SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

We just got a message that SharePoint online is out of storage space. Is there a way to get an overview of file size and location across all our sub-sites similar to [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info) or [DaisyDisk](https://www.daisydiskapp.com)? That would make it a lot easier to figure out where to start culling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go into the admin portal, https://yourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com and see what sites are taking up a large amount of space. From there you can navigate to the site and go to `/_layouts/15/storman.aspx` and this will tell you where the bulk of the storage is being used. Go to the library and prune.

Comment: Thanks, that will work great. Is there a way to get to `/_layouts/15/storman.aspx` through menus or does one just have to know the URL?

Comment: It is also available in Site Settings -> Storage Metrics in the Site Collection Administration section.